# Symfony service arguments ignored

Tags: symfony, listener

I have an entity listener declared with annotation

```
...
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({ "EnvBundle\Listener\UserListener" })
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
...
```

and since that listener should have a parameter injected, say a string, I declared it as a service in the service.yml file

```
services:
    env.listener.user:
        class: EnvBundle\Listener\UserListener
        arguments:    ['humpty dumpty']
```

Listener is roughly like this

```
<?php
namespace EnvBundle\Listener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use EnvBundle\Entity\User;

class UserListener
{

    public function __construct(string $s)
    {
        dump('no good: ' . $s);
    }

    public function prePersist(User $entity, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        dump($entity);
        // die;
    }
}
```

Result is that the parameter injected via the service is ignored and I get the following error

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   EnvBundle\Listener\UserListener::__construct() must be of the type
>   string, none given

Once I declare the constructor without parameter it gets executed. I can't find out what I'm missing to get the parameters injected into the entity listener.

***Edit***: by checking debug:container the service does exist

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your service definition is missing a tag: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/entity-listeners.html and unless you have a very old version of Doctrine then the EntytListener annotation is not required.

Comment: your suggestion looks the right one. I'm still confused because I thought that tags should be optional and that declaring this listener as a service is only useful for passing parameters. If you want to post a complete answer to clearify doubts I'd gladly accept it

Comment: What happens if you add those tags?